# Serial software is not able to write and read the data

Tags: arduino

I am trying to write a data to the software serial port. But I am not able to read the data.
I have used the following code:

```
   #include<SoftwareSerial.h>
  SoftwareSerial mySerial(10, 11); // RX, TX

void setup()  
{
 // Open serial communications and wait for port to open:
 Serial.begin(57600);
 while (!Serial) {
 ; // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for Leonardo only
}


     Serial.println("Goodnight moon!");

 // set the data rate for the SoftwareSerial port
 mySerial.begin(57600);
 mySerial.println("Hello, world!");
 }

 void loop() // run over and over
 {
 if (mySerial.available())
 Serial.write(mySerial.read());
 if (Serial.available())
 mySerial.write(Serial.read());
 }
```

Please can anyone of you help me. Thanks in advance

Comment: What did you plug into your 10th and 11th port ? Did you cross TX and RX ? Rx->Tx and Tx->Rx.

Comment: 57600 is pretty fast for SoftwareSerial. Try 9600 or less.